# webrtc ondataavailable is not working proper in firefox but working well in chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, webrtc

I am using webrtc for upload live video recording.
But I see webrtc (mediarecorder) has diffrent behaviour in firefox and chrome.

```
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  console.log(typeof 500);
  mediaRecorder.start(1000);
```

---

```
function handleDataAvailable(event) {
    console.log('data avail -> ',event.data.size);
}
```

See console log of chrome. I got blob in ondataavailable at every 1 second

**Five second data:**

```
data avail ->  312
data avail ->  12223
data avail ->  12721
data avail ->  12347
data avail ->  12457
data avail ->  10021
data avail ->  10021 continue.....
```

But in firefox I got this log in console

**Five Second data**

```
data avail ->  312
data avail ->  0
data avail ->  0
data avail ->  0
data avail ->  0
data avail ->  255223
data avail ->  0 continue.....
```

So my question is why I am not gettings small blob in firefox but working well in chrome, opera?

Comment: chrome and opera are the same thing. iirc, the exact chunking strategy is left open to the implementation.

Comment: Not sure if it's normal behavior, but you can force FF to fill your chunks with `recorder.requestData()` if this really matters for you. Ah nope, doesn't even work with `requestData`... FF is buggy here (but no worries, chrome is too in so many other places of this API ;-) )

Comment: Yes I also used recorder.requestData() but this will produce same result.Not effect firefox .

Comment: @Divyesh They did a big [rebuild of the MediaRecorder API](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1296531) lately, not sure if it's linked. But you might want to let them know about this bug by opening a new issue.